# no values if null in the referenced table sql access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have table that "reviewers" as a id and a name

```
ID |  Name
1  |  Coolboy
```

Now i have table "Orders" that has a foreign key to the "reviwers" table

```
Order No  | Date | ID  |
```

now some the fields in the "orders" table is null,

so in that case the sql is not working:

```
select o.[order no], o.[date], r.[name] orders o, reviewers r where o.ID = r.ID
```

If there are null values in the "Orders" table then how to show the rows.

how to mix this query with a where clause:

```
SELECT O.[Order No], O.[Date], [R.Name], i.[inv_date] FROM Reviewers R, Invoices i
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.ID = R.ID where  o.[inv_no] =  i.[inv_numb]
```

I have come up with a new question:

[replace multiple left joins in access sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466127/replace-multiple-left-joins-in-access-sql)

Thanks

Pradyut

Comment: huh?  select o.[order no], o.[date], r.[name] orders o, reviewers r where o.ID = r.ID or o.id is null  ?

Comment: won't it select all the o.id with a null?

Comment: I'm confused at what you want exactly.... the left outer join should do it (maybe without the where part, I'm not sure what you're after).  Can you clarify what you want?  I see ID's, [Order No]'s and at the end [inventory_no]'s.

Comment: [This is a continuation of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466127/replace-multiple-left-joins-in-access-sql/).