# replace multiple left joins in access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I m writing a query in **ms access** for three tables "Process Name", "Work_Log1" and "ACn_reviewer".

Now the "Work_Log1" table is having foreign keys to the "Process NAme" and "ACN_REviewer" table.

But the "Work_log1" table is having null values in some rows for "ACN_Reviewer" table.

THe **working** query i have come up with

```
select w.[activity_id], w.[activity_start_date], w.[reporting month] , 
r.[Reviewer_Name] , p.[process_name]
from [process name] p left join 
([work_log1] w left join [acn_reviewer] r
on w.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID]  )
on w.[process] = p.[process_id] 
 where w.[activity_id] = 54447
```

now i know that there are no process ids null in the work_log1 table.

The question i ask is there some way to do the above query without the joins?

Something like this, left join only on acn_reviewer

```
 select w.[activity_id], w.[activity_start_date], w.[reporting month] , 
r.[Reviewer_Name] , p.[process_name]
from [process name] p  ,   [work_log1] w left join [acn_reviewer] r
 on w.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID]   
  where w.[process] = p.[process_id] and 
  w.[activity_id] = 54447
```

I hope now i m clear

So can i write something like this in the sql, which is throwing error in ms-access

```
select w.[activity_id], w.[activity_start_date], w.[reporting month] ,
r.[Reviewer_Name] , p.[process_name] from [process name] p, [work_log1] w 
left join [acn_reviewer] r
on w.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID]  on w.[process] = p.[process_id]
 where w.[activity_id] = 54447 ;
```

Thanks

Pradyut

Comment: what error - exactly - does the second query get?

Comment: oh, you have left join [table] on [condition] on [another condition] so that's an error with sql in general right there.  MS-Access is weird when you want to left join twice.  You must do it with parenthesis and it gets confusing.  Is this kinda along the lines of your issue?  or is njk going in a better direction?

Comment: the first query is actually working.. i missed the point i guess

Comment: ok.  if that query works...... why are you trying to do it without the joins?  what's wrong with the first one? (sorry, please, thanks; trying to answer your question)

Comment: You say the first query works.... so why are you trying to re-write it?  And by "working" do you mean returns the results you desire?  If so... why?  What?  Please, provide a diagram or an example resulting dataset and I'm sure we can get this done and over with really quick... and specifically, where there are NULLS and where you want to see the NULLs returned by the query.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered from the attributes above:

```
Process Name (p)
p.[process_name]
p.[process_id]

Work_Log1 (w)
w.[activity_id]
w.[process]
w.[acn reviwer]
w.[activity_start_date]
w.[reporting month]

ACN Reviewer (r)
r.[acn_reviewer_id]
r.[reviewer_name]
```

[image]

How are `Process Name` and `ACN Reviewer` related? If they aren't, there is no way to bridge them based on a `NULL` value in `Work_Log1`.

Comment: oops.. you missed the question :) its already mentioned there, its already working ;)

Comment: sorry njk, you are not reading quite? I suggest please read more ;). Mentioned in the question "Now the "Work_Log1" table is having foreign keys to the "Process NAme" and "ACN_REviewer" table."

Comment: i still don't understand what is wrong with his diagram.  work_log1 does show FK's for both the process name table and the acn_reviewer table (in his diagram).  Pradyut, if njk's diagram is incorrect - can you give us a better one?

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya The diagram in my answer is based off the statement that `Work_Log1` table has fk's to `Process Name` and `ACN_Reviewer`.

Comment: lets make it really simple :) if there is any way that the query can be done like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465065/no-values-if-null-in-the-referenced-table-sql-access

Answer (score 0):

**last try:**  i am thinking.... maybe you want to union those results to another select with work_log1 left join'd to acn_reviewer (without joining work_log1 with process first) to get the situations where process is null and acn_reviewer is not?  yes?  no...?  who knows.  i'm tired.  Access doesn't allow for full outer joins and stuff so.... maybe that's what you're trying to do, actually?

```
        select  pw.[activity_id], 
                pw.[activity_start_date], 
                pw.[reporting month] ,
                r.[Reviewer_Name], 
                pw.[process_name] 

        from    ([work_log1] as w

                join [process name] as p 
                on w.[process] = p.[process_id] ) as pw

                    join [acn_reviewer] as r
                    on pw.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID]  

        where   pw.[activity_id] = 54447 

        -- all records in work_log1 that have a matching row both
                    -- in acn_reviewer and process via the join 

        union 


        select  pw.[activity_id], 
                pw.[activity_start_date], 
                pw.[reporting month] ,
                null as [Reviewer_Name], 
                pw.[process_name] 

        from    ([work_log1] as w

                join [process name] as p 
                on w.[process] = p.[process_id] ) as pw

                    left join [acn_reviewer] as r
                    on pw.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID]  

        where   pw.[activity_id] = 54447 and r.[acn reviewer] is null

        -- all records where work_log1, WITH a row in process, 
                    -- WITHOUT a row in acn_reviewer 

        union

        select  pw.[activity_id], 
                pw.[activity_start_date], 
                pw.[reporting month] ,
                r.[Reviewer_Name] as [Reviewer_Name], 
                null as [process_name] 

        from    ([work_log1] as w

                join [acn_reviewer] as r
                on w.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID] ) as wr

                    left join [process name] as p 
                    on w.[process] = p.[process_id]  

        where   pw.[activity_id] = 54447 and p.[process_id] is null

        -- all records where work_log1, WITHOUT a row in process, 
                    -- WITH a row in acn_reviewer 

        union


        select  pw.[activity_id], 
                pw.[activity_start_date], 
                pw.[reporting month] ,
                null as [Reviewer_Name], 
                null as [process_name] 

        from    ([work_log1] as w

                left outer join [acn_reviewer] as r
                on w.[ACN Reviwer] = r.[ACN_Reviewer_ID]  ) as wr

                    left outer join [process name] as p 
                    on wr.[process] = p.[process_id]

        where   pw.[activity_id] = 54447 and p.[process_id] is null and wr.[ACN_Reviewer_ID] is null

        -- all records in work_log1 that have no matching rows in either process or acn_reviewier
                    --  cuzzz its a left outer join and the where says the joined tables return null-thing
```

Access is odd and may or may not like it if you put that whole thing into a `select * from (query with unions) as x where activity_id = 54447` but i am not sure.  i haven't tested this.  but you get the idea hopefully.  and hopefully this is what you want.  **IF NOT ---> an ERD like njk provided us/you is correct (b/c you said his was wrong) would be extremely helpful and without it or without an example result set where it shows the NULLs that you need I just can't continue.  **

or... your first query stripped of the joins?

```
select  w.[activity_id], 
        w.[activity_start_date], 
        w.[reporting month], 
        r.[Reviewer_Name], 
        p.[process_name]

from    work_log1 as w, acn_reviewer as r, process as p 

where   (w.[acn reviewer] = r.acn_reviewer_id or r.acn_reviewer_id is null) and 
        w.process = p.process_id
```

Comment: no that's not it, either.  is it?  i keep re-reading the question and i don't understand the null issue.

Comment: null is in the [work_log1] table for the w.[ACN Reviwer] column.

Comment: do we want to see that NULL or not?